# Find integration limits of Probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

I am trying to figure out limits of integration, to find the probability distribution of $P(X<Y-Z)$.

Please verify and correct if I can write like below.

$$P(X<Y-Z)=\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{z=0}^{z=y}\int_{x=0}^{x=y-z}f_{X}(x)\,f_{Y}(y)\,f_{Z}(z)\,dx\,dz\,dy,$$

where $X=M+S$,  $\,\,M\sim Exp(\gamma), \,\,S  \sim Exp(\mu), \,\,Y \sim Exp(\xi)$ and $\,\,Z \sim U(0,Y)$.

We can see $Z$ is dependent on $Y$. I have taken independent above while writing the densities of $X,Y$ and $Z$.

$$P(X<Y-Z)=\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{z=0}^{z=y}\int_{x=0}^{x=y-z}(f_{M}(x)*f_{S}(x))\,\frac{1}{y} \,\xi e^{- \xi  y } \,dx\,dz\,dy.$$

Correct me if i am wrong if I can write above, Please suggest on limits of integration and dependence of $Z=Y$.

$*$ represents the convolution operator. $\,\,Exp()$ represents the exponentially distributed random variable, and $U()$ represents the uniformly distributed random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We can see $Z$ is dependent on the mean of $Y$.

Indeed. Rather, $~Z$ is conditionally dependent on $Y$, which is more correctly indicated by: $Z\mid Y~\sim~\mathcal{U}(0,Y)$

Now let $W=Y-Z$, then by symmetry: $W\mid Y~\sim~\mathcal{U}(0,Y)$, thus:

$$\begin{align}f_{\small W}(w) &= \int_w^\infty f_{\small Y}(y)\,f_{\small W\mid Y}(w\mid y)\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$$

So

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<Y-Z) &= \mathsf P(X<W)\\[1ex]&=\int_0^\infty f_{\small X}(x)\,\mathsf P(x<W)\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&= \int_0^\infty f_{\small X}(x)\,\int_x^\infty f_{\small W}(w)\,\mathrm d w\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\int_0^\infty f_{\small X}(x)\,\int_x^\infty\!\int_w^\infty\! f_{\small Y}(y)\,f_{\small W\mid Y}(w\mid y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d w\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\int_0^\infty [f_{\small S}{\star}f_{\small M}](x)\int_x^\infty\!\int_w^\infty\!\dfrac 1y\,\xi\,\mathsf e^{-\xi y}\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d w\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&~~\vdots \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you @ Graham Kemp, I made some corrections in question, i.e. Z is dependent on Y (not mean). Z is dependent on Y but Y independent of Z,  Can we consider it independent for the same?.

Comment: No, when $Z$ is dependent on $Y$, then $Y$ will also be dependent on $Z$.

Comment: does limits of dy from 0 to infinity also give the same answer? Also, can you brief me about the symmetry used above?

Comment: To first answer the last question: $U\sim \mathcal U(0,n)$ means $(n-U)\sim\mathcal U(0,n)$ too, by the fact that a uniform distribution is symmetric around its mean.

Comment: For the other, as long as the criteria for Fubini's theorem hold: $$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty\!\!\int_x^\infty\!\!\int_w^\infty g(w,x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm dw\,\mathrm d x & = \iiint_{0<x<w<y}g(w,x,y)\,\mathrm d \langle w,x,y\rangle\\&=\int_0^\infty\!\!\int_0^y\!\!\int_0^w g(w,x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm dw\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you Graham Kemp